# Login lacks connect endpoint permission in SQL Server - Error 18456, State: 149

Tags: sql-server, logins, sql-server-2017

I have a fresh database I've setup, which I can connect to and perform operations like normal via the SQL Server Management Studio. I have two accounts I created for my application to use, and both can log in via SSMS. My program is running java and using the 'mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar' driver, and when I attempt to connect I can see the following error on the database log:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, Sate: 149
>   Login failed for user 'application_read_only_user'. Reason:
>   Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure
>   error. Login lacks connect endpoint permission. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

I have looked at several sources trying to solve this issue. The official Microsoft documentation does not seem to list state 149, nor do any results I've found online.

I have not modified my endpoints from the original settings, so I only have the following items:

- Dedicated Admin Connection
- TSQL Local Machine
- TSQL Named Pipes
- TSQL Default TCP
- TSQL Default VIA

I have tried setting the SQL Server services to run as Local System.

There are a lot of similar questions on this site, and stack overflow, but none of them have been able to help. They all either have a different state, or do not list a state.

Comment: Your question prompted me to search the Internet for possible causes and solutions.  I'm not sure if this post will help (you may have already seen it), but take a look at [Why do I get the infrastructure error for login failures?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/07/09/why-do-i-get-the-infrastructure-error-for-login-failures/)

Comment: I have seen that article before, Scott, unfortunately it did not help me. I tried all of those suggestions and none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve this issue. By default, after installation, the TCP/IP connection had been disabled. I needed to open up 'SQL Server Configuration Manager', go to the network configuration section and enable TCP/IP.

Under the 'IP Addresses' menu on TCP/IP I also needed to make sure the IP4 option was active, and the IPAll port matched what I expected the server to be listening under.

hot2use's answer had a lot of potentially useful options for figuring out the issue, but in the end none of them were able to diagnose my exact problem. All results returned from querying the server itself said everything was working correctly, it wasn't until I looked at this tool that I found some settings were not as I expected.

Comment: I've got the same problem as in the original post. All TCP options are correct in the configuration manager. TCP is enabled and listening on port 1433. I still cant connect remotely to my SQL instance though unless I use a sysadmin login. Local connections work fine.

I have verified that public has connect to permission on the endpoint, and the non-SA user that I want to use has connect permission on the server. I've tried restarting SQL,  rebooting, etc. Nothing has worked. 

This is only happening on one of my ~200 servers.

Answer (score 5):

### Analysis

If you have a search for the **Error 18456** you will eventually find the following blog post from Aaron Bertrand:

- [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) (SQL Blog / Aaron)

Which lists the following for `states 146...149`:

> These states replace states 11 and 12 above, but only in SQL Server 2016 or better. The goal was to make the actual underlying issue easier for the sysadmin to diagnose between SQL auth and Windows auth logins, and between connect and endpoint permissions (all without giving any further info to the user trying to log in). For more details, see the latter part of [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/07/09/why-do-i-get-the-infrastructure-error-for-login-failures/).

The **this post** link in the above quote references the article ["Why do I get the infrastructure error for login failures?"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/07/09/why-do-i-get-the-infrastructure-error-for-login-failures/) over on **CSS SQL Server Engineers** blog/site.

The article cites these two possible reasons as the cause for the "Login-based **server access validation failed** with an infrastructure error":

> 1. Does the login have the SERVER class permission named CONNECT SQL for this server instance?
> 2. Does the login have the ENDPOINT class permission named CONNECT for the specific endpoint on which the client application established the connection?

Because SQL Server 2016+ has new error messages for **Level 146...149** errors, you have been presented with the specific error message **Login lacks connect endpoint permission.** (Level 149), which leads you to the second option from above.

Have a look at your current enpoint permissions with the following script:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_permissions AS sp2 
    JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp
        ON sp2.grantee_principal_id = sp.principal_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.endpoints AS e
        on sp2.major_id = e.endpoint_id
WHERE sp2.permission_name = 'CONNECT' 
AND sp2.class_desc = 'ENDPOINT'
```

You should have at least one entry for the combination of `GRANT`, `public` and `TSQL Default TCP`

### Solution

Check the CONNECT permissions on the ENDPOINT for the SQL Server Login for TCP or simply grant the permission to the account:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[TSQL Default TCP] TO public;
```

(replace `public` with your `<SQL Server Login>` if you only want to assign that permission to a specific account)

To see a list of endpoints run:

```
select * from sys.endpoints
```

### Further Reading / Reference List

- [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) (SQL Blog / Aaron)
- [Why do I get the infrastructure error for login failures?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/07/09/why-do-i-get-the-infrastructure-error-for-login-failures/) (CSS SQL Server Engineers)
- [Endpoints Catalog Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/endpoints-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs)
- [GRANT Endpoint Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-endpoint-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: Sorry, hot2use, but this doesn't solve the issue. I've got both SERVER and ENDPOINT connect privileges granted to the user, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, I‘ll dig deeper. Is the user possibly in a group that has been denied permission?

Comment: The one I'm testing with is only a member of the default public group on both master and my application database. On the application database he has the db_datareader role. None of these are disabled or had access revoked.

Comment: Quick one: If you execute my query to list the principal's permissions just without the `WHERE ....` part, do you see any entries containing a `DENY` in the `state_desc` column?

Comment: Nope, nothing has been denied.

Comment: @Seb it's possible they have a stale login_token that requires killing all of those user's sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem because I was trying to connect to port 1434 instead of port 1433. mssql-server is listening to both. I can connect to 1434 and use SA account without problem but that did not work for other accounts.

Comment: 1434 is the DAC port. Only a sysadmin can use it.

Comment: This answer deserve a bit more consideration, I got the exact same error 18456 by using 1434 instead of 1433.